Base image similar to Amazon AMI 2018.03
My question is without having to take an old AMI server snapshot, where can I get an image (ISO or VB vdi etc) very close to the AMI 2018.03 image?
I think? this version was based off Centos while the later AWS images are based off Fedora.  If so is there a Centos version that might be close?
I've tried the latest AWS image from the cdn and am already running into problems, so they won't work for me.  From my target os-release system:
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2018.03"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2018.03"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03"

thank you

"The Amazon Linux AMI (also called Amazon Linux 1) reached its end of life on December 31, 2023. Amazon Linux AMI will not receive any security updates or bug fixes starting January 1, 2024. Customers are encouraged to upgrade their applications to use Amazon Linux 2023, which includes long term support through 2028." https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/

yes I'm aware of that, that's why i'm looking for a similar base to it.  We have a number of servers with it that are not and will not be upgraded anytime soon.

Do the old AMI IDs not work any more? I wonder if they left them available even though they're not meant to be used. Check your old machine for AMI IDs. Though I don't know why you want to create new machines from old images.
